# What am I doing wrong with this drupal 6 module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Whenever I click on the submit button the form is cleared and none of the code inside is executed, despite either I'm setting a drupal message or trying to send an email. I've replaced my email etc with 'user@domain.com'.

```
<?php

/**
 *  implementation of help hook
 */
function module_test_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {    // if the path is equaled to case, return value.
    case 'admin/help#module_test':
      $output .= '<p>' . t('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis dictum turpis.') . '</p>';
      return $output;
     break;
  }
}

/**
 *  implementation of menu hook
 */
/** function module_test_menu() {
*   $items = array();
*   $items['lorem-ipsum'] = array (  
*   'title' => t('Lorem-ipsum'),  
*   'page callback' => '_module_test_page',
*   'access arguments' => array('administer my module'),  
*   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
*   );
*   return $items; 
*   }
**/

function module_test_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['validation_form'] = array (  
  'title' => t('Validation Form'),  
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('module_test_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer my module'),  
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
   );
   return $items; 
}

 /**
*   implementing permissions
**/ 
function module_test_perm() {
  return array('Administer my module');
}  

/**
*   implementing forms with validations
**/ 
function module_test_form() {
  $form['name'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Name'),   
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#size' => '25',
   '#required' => FALSE,
   );

   $form['email'] = array(
   '#title' => t('E-mail'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#size' => '25',   
   '#required' => FALSE,
   '#element_validate' => array('module_test_validate'),
   );

   $form['message'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Message'),
   '#type' => 'textarea',
   '#required' => FALSE,
   );

   $form['checkbox'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Send yourself a copy'),
   '#type' => 'checkbox', 
   '#required' => FALSE,
   '#return_value' => 1,
   '#default_value' => 0
   );

   $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Submit')
   );
   return $form;//
}

/**
*   Validation of e-mail form
**/
function module_test_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    if(!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
     form_set_error('email', 'The email address "' . $valid_email . '" is invalid.');
    }
}

/**
* implementing mail function
*/
function module_test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {

  $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );

  foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }

  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
}



/**
* Create the form submit function
*/
function module_test_submit($form, &$form_state) {


    //main server details
    ini_set("SMTP", "mail.host");
    //smtp port number
    ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
    //send from address
    ini_set("sendmail_from","user@domain.com");

    $admin_email = 'user@domain.com';
    $valid_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $valid_message = $form_state['values']['message'];
    $valid_check = $form_state['values']['checkbox'];

    $from = 'user@domain.com';
    $body = 'Name: ' . $valid_name;
    $body = 'Email: ' . $valid_email;
    $body = 'Message: ' . $valid_message;

    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'ModuleTest Form Confirmation ',
    );

    if($valid_check == 1){
        if (drupal_mail('module_test_form', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from, $send = TRUE))
        {
            form_set_error('checkbox', 'A copy has been sent to ' .$valid_email .'');
        }
    }   
    if (drupal_mail('module_test_form', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from, $send = TRUE))
    {
        drupal_set_message('An email has been sent to ' . $admin_email);      
    } else {
        drupal_set_message('There was an error sending your email');
    }

}
/**
* Return the form.
*/
return drupal_get_form('module_test_form');
?>
```

Comment: tip: you can use php -l yourfile.module to check for syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

missing a } to close your 
function module_test_submit($form, &$form_state) {

hope it helps

PR

Comment: It would appear that I have accidentally deleted the '}' when deleting some code in between the if statement and return.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems but the reason why your submit handler does not work is simply because you have wrong naming convention.

Lets clarify all of these:

You have set the email field to be not required and then assuming the email address field is available in the validate function. Correct it as:

```
$form['email'] = array(
   '#title' => t('E-mail'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#size' => '25',   
   '#required' => TRUE,
   );
```

We allow the standard validate function to validate the email address now.

Your validation function has a problem with sanitizing user input. Correct it as:

```
function module_test_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    if(!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
     form_set_error('email', t('The email address "@email" is invalid.', array('@email' => $valid_email)));
    }
}
```

You can't return anything in an open .module file. Remove this:

```
/**
* Return the form.
*/
return drupal_get_form('module_test_form');
```

Rename validate function like this:

```
function module_test_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
```

and your submit function has several problems. Mainly, its name.

```
/**
* Create the form submit function
*/
function module_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


    //main server details
    ini_set("SMTP", "mail.host");
    //smtp port number
    ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
    //send from address
    ini_set("sendmail_from","user@domain.com");

    $admin_email = 'user@domain.com';
    $valid_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $valid_message = $form_state['values']['message'];
    $valid_check = $form_state['values']['checkbox'];

    $from = 'user@domain.com';
    $body[] = 'Name: ' . check_plain($valid_name);
    $body[] = 'Email: ' . $valid_email;
    $body[] = 'Message: ' . nl2br(check_plain($valid_message));
    $body = implode('<br />', $body);
    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'ModuleTest Form Confirmation ',
    );

    if($valid_check == 1){
        if (drupal_mail('module_test', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from))
        {
            drupal_set_message(t('A copy has been sent to @email', array('@email' => $valid_email)));
        }
    }   
    if (drupal_mail('module_test', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from))
    {
        drupal_set_message(t('An email has been sent to @email', array('@email' => $admin_email)));      
    } else {
        drupal_set_message('There was an error sending your email', 'error');
    }

}
```

OK, below is the full code of the module file that you can copy-paste. it works (I tested). 
try to figure out what are the necessary changes. Be addicted to use t() function whenever possible/suitable.

```
<?php

/**
 *  implementation of help hook
 */
function module_test_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {    // if the path is equaled to case, return value.
    case 'admin/help#module_test':
      $output .= '<p>' . t('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis dictum turpis.') . '</p>';
      return $output;
     break;
  }
}

/**
 *  implementation of menu hook
 */
/** function module_test_menu() {
*   $items = array();
*   $items['lorem-ipsum'] = array (  
*   'title' => t('Lorem-ipsum'),  
*   'page callback' => '_module_test_page',
*   'access arguments' => array('administer my module'),  
*   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
*   );
*   return $items; 
*   }
**/

function module_test_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['validation_form'] = array (  
  'title' => t('Validation Form'),  
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('module_test_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer my module'),  
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
   );
   return $items; 
}

 /**
*   implementing permissions
**/ 
function module_test_perm() {
  return array('Administer my module');
}  

/**
*   implementing forms with validations
**/ 
function module_test_form() {
  $form['name'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Name'),   
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#size' => '25',
   '#required' => FALSE,
   );

   $form['email'] = array(
   '#title' => t('E-mail'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#size' => '25',   
   '#required' => TRUE,
   );

   $form['message'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Message'),
   '#type' => 'textarea',
   '#required' => FALSE,
   );

   $form['checkbox'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Send yourself a copy'),
   '#type' => 'checkbox', 
   '#required' => FALSE,
   '#return_value' => 1,
   '#default_value' => 0
   );

   $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Submit')
   );
   return $form;//
}

/**
*   Validation of e-mail form
**/
function module_test_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    if(!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
     form_set_error('email', 'The email address "' . $valid_email . '" is invalid.');
    }
}

/**
* implementing mail function
*/
function module_test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  // these do not work in Drupal 7 //
  $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );

  foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }

  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
}



/**
* Create the form submit function
*/
function module_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


    //main server details
    ini_set("SMTP", "mail.host");
    //smtp port number
    ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
    //send from address
    ini_set("sendmail_from","user@domain.com");

    $admin_email = 'user@domain.com';
    $valid_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $valid_message = $form_state['values']['message'];
    $valid_check = $form_state['values']['checkbox'];

    $from = 'user@domain.com';
    $body[] = 'Name: ' . $valid_name;
    $body[] = 'Email: ' . $valid_email;
    $body[] = 'Message: ' . nl2br($valid_message);
    $body = implode('<br />', $body);
    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'ModuleTest Form Confirmation ',
    );

    if($valid_check == 1){
        if (drupal_mail('module_test', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from))
        {
            drupal_set_message(t('A copy has been sent to @email', array('@email' => $valid_email)));
        }
    }   
    if (drupal_mail('module_test', 'some_mail_key', $valid_email, language_default(), $params, $from))
    {
        drupal_set_message(t('An email has been sent to @email', array('@email' => $admin_email)));      
    } else {
        drupal_set_message('There was an error sending your email', 'error');
    }

}
```